# selective or exclude subfolder for collaboration on box api

Tags: box-api, box

i am integrating a simple web to box and having a bit of trouble.

i have folder hierarchy of structure like this

```
music 1 folder
  - artist1 folder
  - artist2 folder
music 2 folder
  - artist1 folder
  - artist2 folder
```

i have added a collaboration to share `artist1 folder` (from music 1 folder) and `artist1 folder`(from music 2 folder) to a test account and when i call the box api from test account it all lists the folder on to test account's root folder.

my question is, is there way to retain the hierarchy of folder list such that when i get on test account the folder would only show the collaborated items like this

```
    music 1 folder
      - artist1 folder
    music 2 folder
      - artist1 folder
```

or is there way i can exclude the items that are not collaborated from showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Box uses a "waterfall" permission model, where the permissions for folders trickle down the folder structure, but do not go up. That means that if a user is added as a collaborator on a sub-folder, they will only be able to see that subfolder in their root directory, but not any folders above it (nor would they have an indication that the folder has anything above it).

Because these permissions trickle down, it means that you also cannot hide specific folders that are lower on the folder tree than the item that the user was originally collaborated on.

Comment: ok thank you, the reason that im asking is that if the multiple of same name folder exist in different directory, i need to distinguish them from each other by their parent folder. but without actually giving the collaborator access tot the parent folder itself. i did try the search call by root folder but it doesnt seem to work either. any idea would be helpful.